# How can our EPUB files be rendered similarily across devices?

Tags: epub, device

We will soon be producing EPUB files to distribute cultural and scientific papers. We would like them to render similarily across devices, but we're afraid it will be similar to what browsers were a few years back (hell). Is creating validating EPUB files enough to ensure rendering will be similar across devices? What are the do's and dont's in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's like browsers a few years back.

ePub 2, you're reasonably consistent across devices provided you don't do anything special at all.

ePub 3 — well, the devices that support it at the moment (iBooks, Kindle Fire (sort-of-but-not-really), Nook, and a couple of others) do fairly different things. Part of the reason for that is ePub 3 is largely built off the back of HTML5, which is not exactly standardized across browsers at the moment anyway.

And the problem for you may well be that you want to do ePub 3 because of its MathML support, although it will depend on the kind of scientific papers you're producing.

[Liz Castro](http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com) did a presentation earlier this year at [O'Reilly's Tools of Change conference](http://toc.oreilly.com) about *[ePub in the wild](http://www.toccon.com/toc2012/public/schedule/detail/22073)* (note the PDF linked at this page; there's lots of examples of what I'm about to list below). My brief notes on what is supported by various readers are:

Everyone supports:

- bold and italic
- font-size
- text-indent
- top and bottom margins
- images
- Caveats: NOOK overrides defaults with its own (not publisher defaults), and bold only shows up in certain user-selected fonts

Most support:

- font family
- small caps
- Leading
- Left and right margins
- float and width
- text wrap
- borders, backgrounds
- color

Once you start talking about audio/video overlays, discretionary page breaks, drop-caps, and other neat stuff you have to start doing media-queries, or deciding to target particular platforms and leave others behind. For example, you might just go for Kindle Fire & iBooks at this point, and leave others out, but that's going to be a business decision for you to make down the track.